# World building SE site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

*Edit*  This proposal has entered the commitment phase, if you're interested please take a look:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding?referrer=lXRV2pz-84DT8d_GnskAZQ2  */Edit*

Figured as authors some of you may be interested in this proposal over on Area 51.

[World Building Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding)

The current definition is:

> Proposed Q&A site for creators (authors, game designers, artists, etc.) who are designing their own worlds, universes, continents, or the like, usually drawing heavily on real world science for accuracy and on how real societies come into existence.

Though we are discussing exactly what does and does not fit in.

Answer (score 1):

Great find. The example questions there are problematic, but this could be a nice companion site to Writers.SE.

I've left an answer there to [one of the discussion questions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12842/11765); I hope it's of help in defining the site.

(That said, keep in mind that the example questions are very, very rough and the site's earliest days will help its users define it as much as these questions will.)

Comment: Absolutely agree.  Be nice to my questions they are sensitive. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This site has entered the commitment phase, if you're interested, take a look.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding?referrer=lXRV2pz-84DT8d_GnskAZQ2

Answer (score 0):

This site entered private beta yesterday.  If you committed you should have gotten email.  If you didn't you can ask someone who did (like me) for an invitation.  Otherwise, be on the lookout for it in a couple weeks, assuming private beta goes well.

It's got some interesting questions.

Comment: I'm interested in the site, and I'm looking forward to seeing what it becomes. If it becomes a going concern, I think some of the worldbuilding questions we ended up closing here early on could probably do well on such a site.